# Dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows 7 upgrade to Ubuntu 16

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, windows, iso

I installed Ubuntu 3 years ago and an upgrade attempt failed. The disk was configured dual-boot with Ubuntu + Windows.

I tried to install an ISO file for Ubuntu 16.

How can upgrade my previous Ubuntu installation to Ubuntu 16 without losing the dual-boot or Windows!?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ubuntu do you currently have installed?

You can install Ubuntu on the same partitions were the old version of Ubuntu is the process is the same as any other installation

When you run the live session of Ubuntu and begin your installation choose Something else, them choose the same partition were the old Ubuntu is installed and begin the installation

Don't not touch any of the Windows partitions and you should be good to go

Comment: thansk for quick replay 

my ubuntu version is so old I think Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope) or maybe before

ok if I do those steps what about the boot loader do I have to make it as the old times?

Comment: If system is that old, you may be better off with Lubuntu or Xubuntu. Which are lighter weight systems. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu#System_Requirements

Comment: Agreed, xUbuntu is a fine choice for older hardware (2GB RAM).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, upgrades from 14->16 are prone to serious failure (unusable).  I would make a disk backup with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php) before doing anything and ensure that any mistake is recoverable.  This will invoke Murphy's law and can increase your chances of success.

Install your favorite Linux distribution (Ubuntu) on the old partition as described by Rob Goss below.  Be sure to let us know if you are successful and the steps you followed.